# Explanation of bash calculator code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, calculator

Can someone explain me this bash code?

```
read text && echo $text | bc -l
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be brief: read user input, pass it to `bc` command and output its result.

More on bc command: http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html

**Step by step explanation:**

```
read text && echo $text | bc -l
```

`read text`
Reads a line from the standard input and saves it in the `text` variable.

`&&`
Lets you do something based on whether the previous command completed successfully.

`echo`
Display message to the standar output.

`$text`
Retrieves the value of the `text` variable.

`|`
A pipe lets you use the output of a program as the input of another one

`bc -l`
bc is an arbitrary precision calculator language. 
-l is an option defining the standard math library.

So, the full code:

1. Reads a line from the standard input (keyboard) and saves it to a
   variable named `text`
2. Outputs the value of the `text` variable to `bc`
3. If the user input contains a mathematical expression, `bc` will return the result.

Usage:

```
$ read text && echo $text | bc -l
(3+3)*2 <-- user input containing a mathematical expression
12      <-- result
```

Comment: Can you explain me every single passage, please?